# How to convert 2d array to 1d array to show in view

Tags: grails

I have a data to render to a view like this,

```
['harry', ['foo','bar']]
```

I want to change them into

```
['harry', 'foo', 'bar']
```

Because when I rendered them to view like this

```
<g:each var="user" in="${users}">
<li>
${user.name}
</li>
</g:each>
```

The result will be shown like

[harry]

[foo,bar]

How can I dow ?
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call `.flatten()` on your list, e.g. `<g:each var="user" in="${users.flatten()}">` (or even better, do it in your controller before you pass the data into the view).

Answer (score 1):

`flatten()` would, well, flatten nested lists.

```
assert ['harry', 'foo', 'bar']==['harry', ['foo','bar']].flatten()
```